# php var not splitting for returns (button)

Tags: php, var

i have a var.

```
$text = "";
```

User are able to edit this in a textbox.

lets say i enter the following:

> "hello, how are you?
>   i am typing random stuff on a second line."

this var shows up in the textbox on a second line, but when i display the var.

```
<?php echo $text; ?>
```

It displays like this.

> "hello, how are you? i am typing random stuff on a second line."

Why doesn't it spill when i echo the var?
is there a way to make it do so?

Sorry this is a dumb question, but when i google the question it thinks i mean return a var or enter a var.

Comment: Where is the code you have tried so far?

Comment: There will be no second line in a textbox.

Comment: @syedsuleman presume the OP is refgering to `textarea` not `input`

Comment: Check @Steve answer. it works

Comment: sorry yes i ment textarea.
it does show the (returns) in the textarea, but not when i echo it out.
someone did explain i can use pre, but it keeps canceling out all my css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New line characters are ignored in most html tags, so if you want to display this text in a browser, you will either need to wrap in `pre` tags:

```
echo '<pre>' . $text . '</pre>';
```

Or use phps `nl2br` function to replace line breaks with html `br` tags:

```
echo nl2br($text);
```

If you just want to confirm the line breaks are included in the variable, you can just view page source to see them

Comment: pre shows the line breaks, but cancels out any css other then color.
so i know it is possible thanks for the help, i will keep working at it and see what i can come up with.

Comment: Actually i got the n12br to work, thank you so much Steve. It is exactly what i was looking for!

I'm glad someone understood my horrible explanation.

Comment: @DillonBurnett No problem, glad i could help